# Find number in URL

Tags: php, regex, url

I have URL path example:

```
1. /1/another.part?param1=1&param2=2
2. /1000/another.part2?param1=1&param2=2
```

How can I get 1 or 1000 (number between / and /) using php?

Thanks.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** `explode` function

```
$str = explode('/','/1/another.part?param1=1&param2=2');
echo $str[1];
```

Comment: @user889349 always welcome dear...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
var number=document.location.href.split('?')[1]
```

Comment: Isn't that javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions [preq_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)

**PHP**

```
preq_match("\/[0-9]*\/", $string);
```